# IAP sandbox testing not showing products list

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am doing one application.In that i written the code for IAP testing like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];
     SKProductsRequest *req = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:      [NSSet                                                                                setWithObjects:@"com.companyname.testing.sampleitem",nil]];
  req.delegate = self;
  [req start];
 }
 - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{

NSArray *array=response.products;
NSLog(@"Products are %d",[array count]);
for(SKProduct *product in response.products){
    SKPayment *myPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:myPayment];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

}
}
```

But every time,it printing the Products are 0.I am using the development provisioning profile for code signing.And same bundle id for registering the items in itunesconnect.My application status is "Waiting for upload" in itunesconnect.And all bank details are also added to my itunesconnect account.So please help me how to get the product details.

Comment: are you testing in simulator?

Comment: What is your product status?

Comment: I am testin in device only.And application status is waiting for upload and IAP product status is Waiting for screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

InApp Testing will not work in simulator, check with a device.

Comment: I am testing in device only

Comment: change that waiting for upload status in itunes to ready for sale

Comment: the product status...not application status

Comment: I want to test the application in sandbox environment.Not ready to test really.

Answer (score 0):

If testing on simulator, make sure you use iOS 6 Simulator, otherwise StoreKit won't work.

If you just created the purchases in iTunesConnect maybe the solution is that you just need to wait a bit for them to be available.
Sometimes it can take 24 hours, other times it's a few minutes.

Also com.companyname.testing.sampleitem in your code should be exactly the IAP's product ID. Otherwise it won't show in the products request.

Comment: Yes, In-App-Purchases work in iOS 6 Simulator (for testing in sandbox only).

You should get products list, and make purchases with an iTunes test user account.